# Inserting XML snippet into another XML document in Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

The following code snippet should insert the fragment XML into body, right after elem.

```
def body = '''
    <parent>
        <child>
          <elem>
            <name>Test</name>
          </elem>
        </child>
    </parent>
'''

def fragment = '''
    <foo>
        <bar>hello!</bar>
        <baz/>
    </foo>
'''

def bodyNode     = new XmlParser().parseText(body)
def fragmentNode = new XmlParser().parseText(fragment)

bodyNode.child*.appendNode(fragmentNode)

def newFileName= '/Users/xxx/out.xml'
def writer = new FileWriter(newFileName)
new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer)).print(bodyNode)
```

Expected content of out.xml:

```
<parent>
   <child>
      <elem>
         <name>Test</name>
      </elem>
      <foo>
         <bar>hello!</bar>
         <baz/>
      </foo>
   </child>
</parent>
```

However what I am getting instead is:

```
<parent>
   <child>
      <elem>
         <name>Test</name>
       </elem>
       <foo/>
   </child>
</parent>
```

As you can see the content of foo element is omitted. What is the reason for this behavior and how can I achieve the correct output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reason**:

use of `appendNode()` instead of `append()`. Try this instead:

```
bodyNode.child*.append(fragmentNode)
```

**Alternatively**

This is one way to achieve the correct output using `XmlSlurper`:

```
def body = '''
    <parent>
        <child>
          <elem>
            <name>Test</name>
          </elem>
        </child>
    </parent>
'''

def fragment = '''
    <foo>
        <bar>hello!</bar>
        <baz/>
    </foo>
'''

def slurper      = new XmlSlurper( false, false, false )
def bodyNode     = slurper.parseText( body )
def fragmentNode = slurper.parseText( fragment )

bodyNode.child << fragmentNode

def sw = new StringWriter()
groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(bodyNode, sw)
println sw.toString()
```

Comment: Thanks, using append works (what would be the difference btw?). Also +1 for XmlUtil.serialize, way more readable than XmlNodePrinter.

Comment: Read through the descriptions of first two methods in the api. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Node.html

Answer (score 2):

Working example with use of `XmlParser`:

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def body = '''
    <parent>
        <child>
          <elem>
            <name>Test</name>
          </elem>
        </child>
    </parent>
'''

def fragment = '''
    <foo>
        <bar>hello!</bar>
        <baz/>
    </foo>
'''

def bodyNode     = new XmlParser().parseText(body)
def fragmentNode = new XmlParser().parseText(fragment)

bodyNode.child[0].children().add(fragmentNode)

println(XmlUtil.serialize(bodyNode))
```

Comment: This will add `<foo>` as sibling to `<child>` because add() to children() will just append at the bottom of the dom. I guess `<foo>` needs to be a child of `<child>`.

Comment: `bodyNode.child[-1].children().add(fragmentNode)` ;)