# Groovy : replace one XML node with another

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to replace one node containing 3 subnodes with a new node, containing 2 subnodes.

The replaceNode function (http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.html) only accepts Closure, and not an object like replaceBody does.

However, replaceBody replaces the body of the node, not the actual node.

I made a simplified example, which can be ran in https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/

```
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.*;
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil;

class swarco_updated_example_replace_node_test_simple {
static void main(def args){

/* Overlapping entries */
String xmlorg3entries = '''
<map>
    <value>
        <!-- Overlapping registrations -->
        <map>
            <name>blabla</name>
            <fruits>
                <map>
                    <type>pear</type>
                    <color>green</color>
                </map>
                <map>
                    <type>orange</type>
                    <color>orange</color>
                </map>
                <map>
                    <type>cherry</type>
                    <color>red</color>
                </map>
            </fruits>
        </map>
    </value>
</map>
''';

String xmlreplace2entries =  '''
            <fruits>
                <map>
                    <type>grapes</type>
                    <color>green</color>
                </map>
                <map>
                    <type>apples</type>
                    <color>green</color>
                </map>
            </fruits>
''';


    printNodeReplace(xmlorg3entries, xmlreplace2entries);
}

static def printNodeReplace(mainNodeAsString, insertNodeAsString){
                //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352052/inserting-xml-snippet-into-another-xml-document-in-groovy
                 def bodyNode     = new XmlSlurper( false, false, false ).parseText( mainNodeAsString );
                 def fragmentNode = new XmlSlurper( false, false, false ).parseText( insertNodeAsString );
                 //fails
                 //bodyNode.value.map.fruits.replaceNode(fragmentNode);
                 bodyNode.value.map.fruits.replaceBody(fragmentNode);
                 println XmlUtil.serialize(bodyNode);
            }

}
```

The result is a duplicated  node. What is the proper way to do this? Clear the existing  node and use append for each  entry?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><map>
  <value>
    <map>
      <name>blabla</name>
      <fruits>
        <fruits>
          <map>
            <type>grapes</type>
            <color>green</color>
          </map>
          <map>
            <type>apples</type>
            <color>green</color>
          </map>
        </fruits>
      </fruits>
    </map>
  </value>
</map>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `fragmentNode.children()` to append children of the `fragmentNode`

```
bodyNode.value.map.fruits.replaceBody(fragmentNode.children());
```